# Iframe Width not working

Tags: width, facebook-canvas

I really could use some help, I have width set to fluid and it is not displaying our website correctly. I am thinking maybe I need to put some coding into the website itself to make the width populate correctly.

Any advise would be appreciated. Here is the link: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Dolly-Couture/121902929539?sk=app_261546067227561

Answer (score 0):

I think "Fluid Canvas" is only for canvas applications, not Page Tab applications.